# How to deform a plane with multiple hook shaped cutouts? (match attached image)

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

**Disclaimer:** I’m very new to Blender.

I’ve loaded in this image as a reference to essentially trace by deforming a plane:

[image]

My best result so far has been by subdividing the plane with loop cuts, deleting unwanted vertices and edges, and dragging the remaining vertices to line up with the reference's edges. But I'm not sure how to get the vertices to align properly with a curve modifier. I've tried grouping vertices and applying a curve modifier to them, but I keep getting the corners of the mesh flipping over themselves.

I've also tried wrapping the plane in a lattice modifier, and tracing free hand with a Bézier curve.

End goal is to extrude, bevel corners, and export as stl.

Edit: adding image of best attempt, edges are more jagged than desired (I also messed up the rotation of the reference)

[image]

and highlighted faces from @moonboots response

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you've done already and what you want to do next. As I understand it you have changed a plane to fit the shape. And you want to extrude and bevel it. So I don't know why you don't just extrude and bevel it but struggle with a curve or lattice modifier?

Comment: Could you please show your best attempt so far? I think you should extrude a vertex all along the outer shape, then fill with quads, extrude, etc

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I tried following the guidelines/automated suggestions and that ended up  reshaping my question into something less direct. 
What I originally wanted to ask is how more proficient users would approach modeling this piece/what the simplest or most blender-y way to create it would be.

Comment: @moonboots happy to share what I have once I get home to my machine!

Answer (score 1):

You can extrude a vertex all along the shape:

[image]

Then fill with quads:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Bevel the edges (you'll need to edit to avoid any intersecting), etc:

[image]

To make the slope smoother just slide (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) the edges like that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Honestly not too far off from my current version (which I’ll post later), but looks much cleaner and simpler to produce. How would I go about smoothing the side faces/aligning the vertices so that the perimeters are more perfectly curved?

Comment: Could you please highlight the parts you're talking about? If you want smoother slopes, just move the vertices inwards

Comment: I just edited my question with my best attempt and highlighted the faces I referred to above. I'd like the side/outward facing edges to be as smooth/perfectly curved as possible along the yellow lines, like the reference.

Comment: @lepton4 I've edited my answer, is it what you want to know?